# How linux daemon will read xml file in worker service .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, daemon

I am working with new `worker service` project template in `.Net Core`. Reading credentials from config file. Config file location in windows machine `"D:/LC2/Files/Config.xml".`

When I will run `worker service` as `linux daemon`, how `linux` will read config file? because there is only `windows` machine's path available not `linux`.

This is my code to read config file

```
static List<intervalValue> GetConfig()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("D:/LC2/Files/Config.xml");
    XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/parameters/intervalValue");
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            IntervalTypeList.Add(new intervalValue { Name = node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["Name"].Value);
        }
    }
    return IntervalTypeList;
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that a Linux daemon will not be able to read paths that dont exist on Linux.

There are a couple of approaches you can look at:

1. Your services can look at the OS and read a different path/file on Linux. For example, for Windows you are reading the hard-coded location `@'D:\LC2\Files\Config.xml'`, and on Linux, you can use another hard-coded like `/opt/LC2/config.xml`.
2. You can provide an argument to the worker service. That requires parsing arguments and teaching your worker service about an argument, like `--config /path/to/file`. Then your worker service will just read that passed-in path and not have to worry about the path. Whatever runs/configures your service will provide a correct path on Windows and on Linux.
3. You can add support for reading the file location via an environment variable like `LC2_CONFIG`. If it's set and points to a file, use that location as the config file. Otherwise fall back to the hard-coded value. On Linux, the tool that runs your daemon can provide it a path that is appropriate for Linux.

There are other options and variants possible, but these seem like the most obvious approaches.

Depending on the audience of the program, you might want all three. For example, `git` will use a default location for a config file. But it will let users provide specific configuration values both via command line and also let users specify configuration via environment variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using `DOTNET_CLI_HOME' environment variable to spec` in the `.service` file. will this be useful.

Comment: Sure, but can you help figure out what you want you are looking for? I am sure people can write a few chapter's worth of information on it.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I have tried to create a file but not working only for linux. pl have a look on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62255952/in-workerservice-file-generation-not-working-only-for-linux-net-core