# In WorkerService File generation not working only for Linux .Net Core

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, service

I have to create a `text` file on `linux` when the service is starting. I tried to keep `IsOSPlatform` to recognize `OS` and based on it, I have written code to create a text file for logs. Below is the code which not generating the file only for `linux`, for `windows` it creates a file.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool isLinux = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation
                                       .IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux);

    if(isLinux)
    {
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine("~", "MyLog", "Config.xml");
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.File(sourceFile).CreateLogger();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.File(@"C:\temp\Workerservice\logfile.txt").CreateLogger();
    }

    IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    host.Services.UseScheduler(scheduler =>
    {
        scheduler
          .Schedule<ReprocessInvocable>()
          .EveryThirtySeconds();
    });
    host.Run();
}
```

How can I get it work?

Comment: Did you get any errors? Have you tried to debug this code on linux?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - I didn't get error. I can't debug this code in Linux as I have this code in windows machine and am using virtual linux machine. My daemon running successfully.

Comment: You can always setup WSL and debug your code from windows maichine